# How to properly operate with file here?

Tags: python

Program description:

> Program creates a `.txt` file with the given name from the first input. After that it accepts text lines for the file from each input, until the input only consists of a string `"end"` (this end line should not be included). The program should also handle all possible errors.

My very unprofessional solution:

```
def readf(f,st):
  try:
    assert st == "end", "* End of the file (not included)"
  f.write("\n"+st)
def mainf(f,st):
  try:
    readf(f,st)
  except IOError:
    print("Unexpected error")
  except AssertionError as sterr:
      print(sterr)
t = input("* Beggining of the file (.txt supported only): ")
f = open(t,"w+")
while True:
  exec_st = input()
  if exec_st = 'end':
    f.close
    break
  else:
    mainf(f,st)
```

Problems:

1. I think that the way I accept each string can be improved.
2. I also think that I may have an extra function I can't really understand how to get rid of it.
3. I think that my error handling could be improved (one is enough, or I haven't mentioned all of them).

Comment: If you code works fine but you just want to improve it, you can try re-formulating this post to fit the rules of http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and then posting it there.

Comment: You never call `readf()` or `mainf()`.

Comment: Did you copy the instructions correctly? I think it should say "until the input consists only of `end`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your style **really** confusing, so I rewrote it for you. I also have tested it. It prints a newline at the top of the file, which is good for appending, but I did not want to make your code more obfuscated, so I left out checking if the file was empty. Hope this is helpful!

```
def readf(f, st): # Rename this so it reflects that it writes, not reads
    #try:
        #assert st == "end", "* End of the file (not included)"
    if st == "end":
        return "end"
    
    else:
        f.write("\n" + st)

def mainf(f, st): # Rename this so it reflects that is handles errors
    try:
        if readf(f, st) == "end":
            print("End of file")
    #except AssertionError as sterr:
    #    print(sterr)

    except IOError as err:
        print(f"Unexpected error: {err}") # Edited this to help with debugging


t = input("Beginning of the file (.txt supported only): ")
assert t.endswith(".txt"), "txt only" # Enforce txt

#f = open(t, "w+")
with open(t, "a") as f: # a not w+, because you are not reading the file.
    while True:
        ans = input("> ")
        if ans == "end":
            break
        else:
            #f.write("\n"+ans) # Will make an extra space you do not
            f.write(f"\n{ans}")
```

Answer (score 2):

since `readf` and `mainf` don't seem to be used, you could get rid of those. also you could add a loop to make shour that the end of the filename is 'txt'

```py
while True:
  t = input("* Beggining of the file (.txt supported only): ")
  if not t.endswith('.txt')
    print(".txt supported only")
    continue
  break
```